# has anyone else got a "temporary" worker?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I just got 2 in a row- they both say temporary in green where the job should be. I tried giving them a job in a food level but got no bux for it. I think it's a glitch.

Comment: After the update yesterday they changed from temporary to some of the new levels that were released. Mystery solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I had workers defined as "imposters" before the last update. I kept one and soon it became apparent that they were favorite workers for an unlocked level.

Perhaps you are experiencing a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your app is updated to the latest version, force quit your app and re-enter your app. Voila! :)

Answer (score -1):

I can go one better. I have 3 levels named "temporary". I have built every level and unlocked every scene. I was waiting for levels to become unlocked, and I just tried to buy some residential levels and it kept giving me levels. They each cost about 1.5 million credits. Now they are built and they do nothing. I have a "temporary" worker, and he is not a favorite for a "temporary" level.

I hope an update comes out to release all the crap I just built.